# git, how to find all matching files and revert to previous commit

Tags: git

I have a long list of files in my commit that have been pushed up to the repo. I want to reset a set of those files back to a previous commit, but keep the changes I've made to the rest.

For example:

- foldername1
- foldername3
- foldername4

I want to revert the changes to all files (around 500 files) in foldername3 without having to do it manually for each file.

Answer (score 2):

Just one folder, entire, no exceptions? That's easy — checkout the folder from the previous commit:

```
gt checkout HEAD~ -- foldername3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, how does it know to checkout to a specific commit?

Comment: Replace `HEAD~` with the commit reference?

Comment: @AlexKnopp You asked about previous commit — it's `HEAD~`. If you mean "any old commit" — then just name the commit in the command: SHA1 ID or any revision name like `HEAD~10`.